# Is there a Rawblock-like feature for docx Writers?

Tags: python, docx, pandoc

When I convert from Markdown to LaTeX, I can replace Images or RawBlocks with special LaTeX code using python filters. Is there a similar way to do this for docx output?

In fact, I would like to use python-docx to generate tables which are more complex than what pandoc can handle. I can extract the xml related to the table and I would like to insert that into the document using a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as can be seen [in the pandoc source code](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs#L782), the format should be:

```
RawBlock (Format "openxml") "<customXML></customXML>"
```

or

```
RawInline (Format "openxml") "<customXML></customXML>"
```